# CSS3 Responsive Menu Dropdown não estão funcionando!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css3

Bem, eu quero usar este menu aqui http://codepen.io/emredenx/pen/ojcxl

Ele não funciona no blogger http://menuteste158.blogspot.com.br/ e eu tentei em vários templates diferentes também.

Eu baixei o arquivo e ele funcionou perfeitamente... Então pensei que o problema seria no blogger.. ai eu fui testar no jsfiddle pra ter certeza ( https://jsfiddle.net/5f6s5tcz/ ) e também não funcionou, eu coloquei os mesmos códigos dos arquivos que eu baixei, e o resultado foi o mesmo com o do blogger.

> Se fosse apenas no blogger, poderia ser conflitos entre códigos, mas eu
>   testei em 4 lugares diferentes, e o problema persiste em dois deles...

Eu coloquei comentários no blogger com as partes do menu, para facilitar um pouco mais.

```
<!--menu-->

<!--script menu-->

<!--menu jquery-->
```

Eu já coloquei o jquery depois `<head>` e antes do `</body>` e não teve diferença também, e outra coisa que eu mudei apenas no blogger,a pedido do blog, foi está parte do código:

```
if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
```

Por está:

```
if ($(window).width() &lt;= mediasize) {
```

Agora, eu não poderia está mais confusa... Eu não sei o que mudar e nem porque. são os mesmos códigos em lugares de diferentes.

**Obs.:** O erro deste código no jsfiddle, era porque precisava importar o jquery... Como na foto, apesar deu achar que já estava importando-o neste código (que é o mesmo que foi baixado junto com o menu)  `<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'>`, aparentemente eu não estava.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, apesar da mudança nos códigos do blog, nada mudou.

Comment: http://menuteste158.blogspot.com.br/ o blog

Comment: Você deveria preparar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve), senão fica realmente difícil alguém se interessar em te ajudar com a sua dúvida.

Comment: Está um pouco melhor agora? @LuizVieira

Comment: Sim. :) Votei para reabrir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O menu não estava funcionando no blogger, por conta desta modificação no javascript:

`if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {` e `if ($(window).width() &lt;= mediasize) {`

O código estava dando este erro:
[error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing) after argument list](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125007/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list/125008#125008)

Apesar deu ter feito a modificação por conta do erro `The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.`que o blogger estava dando, pois alguns caracteres não são aceitos no código xml.

Mas há uma forma de fazer com que os aceite, que é adicionando uma seção CData. Como isto:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
(function($) {
  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
    var cssmenu = $(this),
      settings = $.extend({
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).find(".button").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
          mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
        } else {
          mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });
      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
          } else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
          }
        });
      };
      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
      else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
      if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
      resizeFix = function() {
        var mediasize = 700;
        if ($(window).width() > mediasize) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }
        if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      format: "multitoggle"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
//]]>
</script>
```

E agora o menu está funcionando normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Baixei os arquivos e descompactei e funcionou na minha maquina usando google chrome e firefox. Este exemplo precisa de jquery para funcionar. Verifique se na sua aplicação esta "chamando" o jquery.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na minha pergunta agora, eu a modifiquei... Eu acredito que eu expliquei melhor...