# error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing) after argument list

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou querendo colocar um menu no meu blog, que não está funcionando [CSS3 Responsive Menu Dropdown não estão funcionando!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117781/css3-responsive-menu-dropdown-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A3o-funcionando)... E eu acho que isso pode acontecer devido a esse erro no javascript **( mas como não tenho certeza se o que está causando o problema é o erro, separei a pergunta para não ficar confuso)**:

> *Uncaught SyntaxError: missing) after argument list*

Este é o javascript

```
<script>
(function($) {
  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
    var cssmenu = $(this),
      settings = $.extend({
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).find(".button").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
          mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
        } else {
          mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });
      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
          } else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
          }
        });
      };
      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
      else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
      if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
      resizeFix = function() {
        var mediasize = 700;
        if ($(window).width() > mediasize) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }
        if ($(window).width() &lt;= mediasize) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      format: "multitoggle"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

E está é a parte do código relacionada ao erro:

```
cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
```

Eu pesquisei sobre este erro, mas as respostas eram bem exclusivas para cada código... Ai fica difícil olhar um código e saber qual é o problema.

blogs com o menu/erro:
http://95555558888899999999.blogspot.com.br/ 
http://menuteste158.blogspot.com.br/

> **Obs.:** Existe algum site de erros onde tem listado vários erros e suas
>   causas? Seria de longe muito bom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É por conta desse trecho na função `resizeFix` onde tens `&lt;=` no código:

```
if ($(window).width() &lt;= mediasize) {
   cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
}
```

O correto seria:

```
if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
   cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
}
```

Comment: Mas o blog não aceita `<=`  por isso eu modifiquei...

Comment: acho que se eu criasse um javascript externo, talvez funcionasse. Vou tentar.

Comment: Como assim "não aceita"? Se está dentro de um bloco `<script>`, por que não aceitaria?

Comment: porque arquivo xml não aceita.. Se eu deixar aparece uma mensagem de erro... `The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338538/error-parsing-xhtml-the-content-of-elements-must-consist-of-well-formed-charact

Comment: Tente usar [CDATA](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103424/4808) nesse teu código, ficando [assim](http://pastebin.com/raw/12Vtst1G).

Comment: sim @renan obrigada, era por este motivo que o menu não estava funcionando, e eu achava que cdata não servia para nada, agora vale dá uma pesquisada no assunto... ;)